# Can anything go in a function?

Tags: python, function

I have been trying to implement functions in my morse code <–> English translator, but when I tried, I got error messages. Here is before:

```
english = [ "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p",            # list all translateable english characters
            "q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6",
            "7","8","9","0",".",",",";",":","!","?","(",")","-","_","&","=",
            "+","$","/","'"," ", "", "",'"']

morse = [ ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",           # list all translateable morse code characters, in same order
          ".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",
          ".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....",
          "-....","--...","---..","----.","-----",".-.-.-","--..--","-.-.-.",
          "---...","-.-.--","..--..","-.--.","-.--.-","-....-","..--.-",
          ".-...","-...-",".-.-.","...-..-","-..-.",".----.","/", " ", "", ".-..-."]




morselesson = '''Morse code is a telecommunications language made of dots,      
dashes, spaces, and slashes. The letters are comprised of
dots and dashes. Spaces are represented with slashes, and
gaps between letters marked with spaces. '''                                    # Quick morse lesson from Wikipedia. 



print("\nNote: not all characters are logged. \n\n")                            # stuff
print("Enter '!tell me about morse code' for a brief lesson about morse code. \n")
print('''Otherwise, type your morse code or english and it will be
translated to the other language. ''')

while True:


    tobetranslated = input("\nTranslate\n\n> ").lower()           # get input, make all letter cases the same




    if tobetranslated == "!tell me about morse code":                          # if lesson is requested, give lesson
        print(morselesson)
        
    else:                                                               # if not special inquiry: 
        
        try:                                                                                # MORSE TO ENGLISH
            direction = True
            
            tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace(" ", "π")                                   # change spaces between letters into split markers (untypeable character)
            tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace(" / ", "π/π")                                # change morse spaces into english spaces and an untypeable character


            splitupinput = list(tobetranslated.split("π"))                                      # split along the untypeable characters, leaving spaces, and splits
            
            finishedoutput = ""                                                                 # create variable for the end output, to be modified

            
            for i in splitupinput:                      # "for every character in this string:"

                if i in splitupinput:                                                        # IF inputted character is valid:
                    morselocation = morse.index(i.strip())                                          # find location of input morse coded text in the morse code list
                    finishedoutput = finishedoutput + english[morselocation]                    # add segment of translated text to text, separation is already there

            print("\n"+finishedoutput+"\n")                       # when done with translating, display translated text
            wrongdirection = input("Press [ENTER] to translate. \n\nIf translating direction has been detected wrong, press any key and press [ENTER].\n\n")

                    

        except:                                                                             # ENGLISH TO MORSE
            direction = False
            
            tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace("π", " ")                                   # undoing what "try" did
            tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace("π/π", " / ")
            splitupinput = list(tobetranslated)                                                 # divide input into individual characters to be translated
            finishedoutput = ""                                                                 # create variable for the end output, to be modified
            
            for i in splitupinput:                                                  # "for every character in this string:"

                if i in english:                                                        # IF inputted character is valid:
                    
                    englishlocation = english.index(i)                                      # Find location of input character in English character list
                    finishedoutput = finishedoutput + morse[englishlocation] + " "          # Add segment of translated text to output, and add separation
                    
            print("\n"+finishedoutput+"\n")                       # when done with translating, display translated text
            wrongdirection = ""
    
    if wrongdirection == "":
            pass
    else:
                 # morse to english was wrong, english to morse now

        tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace("π", " ")                                   # undoing what "try" did
        tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace("π/π", " / ")
        splitupinput = list(tobetranslated)                                                 # divide input into individual characters to be translated
        finishedoutput = ""                                                                 # create variable for the end output, to be modified
        
        for i in splitupinput:                                                  # "for every character in this string:"

            if i in english:                                                        # IF inputted character is valid:
                
                englishlocation = english.index(i)                                      # Find location of input character in English character list
                finishedoutput = finishedoutput + morse[englishlocation] + " "          # Add segment of translated text to output, and add separation
                
        print("\n"+finishedoutput+"\n")                       # when done with translating, display translated text
```

As you can see, the English to morse is used twice. So, I decided to define the translating bits as functions, and use those.

```
english = [ "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p",            # list all translateable english characters
            "q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6",
            "7","8","9","0",".",",",";",":","!","?","(",")","-","_","&","=",
            "+","$","/","'"," ", "", "",'"']

morse = [ ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",           # list all translateable morse code characters, in same order
          ".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",
          ".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....",
          "-....","--...","---..","----.","-----",".-.-.-","--..--","-.-.-.",
          "---...","-.-.--","..--..","-.--.","-.--.-","-....-","..--.-",
          ".-...","-...-",".-.-.","...-..-","-..-.",".----.","/", " ", "", ".-..-."]


def mte():
    tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace(" ", "π")                                   # change spaces between letters into split markers (untypeable character)
    tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace(" / ", "π/π")                                # change morse spaces into english spaces and an untypeable character


    splitupinput = list(tobetranslated.split("π"))                                      # split along the untypeable characters, leaving spaces, and splits
    
    finishedoutput = ""                                                                 # create variable for the end output, to be modified

    
    for i in splitupinput:                      # "for every character in this string:"

        if i in splitupinput:                                                        # IF inputted character is valid:
            morselocation = morse.index(i.strip())                                          # find location of input morse coded text in the morse code list
            finishedoutput = finishedoutput + english[morselocation]                    # add segment of translated text to text, separation is already there

def etm():
    tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace("π", " ")                                   # undoing what "try" did
    tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace("π/π", " / ")
    splitupinput = list(tobetranslated)                                                 # divide input into individual characters to be translated
    finishedoutput = ""                                                                 # create variable for the end output, to be modified
    
    for i in splitupinput:                                                  # "for every character in this string:"

        if i in english:                                                        # IF inputted character is valid:
            
            englishlocation = english.index(i)                                      # Find location of input character in English character list
            finishedoutput = finishedoutput + morse[englishlocation] + " "          # Add segment of translated text to output, and add separation
    
morselesson = '''Morse code is a telecommunications language made of dots,      
dashes, spaces, and slashes. The letters are comprised of
dots and dashes. Spaces are represented with slashes, and
gaps between letters marked with spaces. '''                                    # Quick morse lesson from Wikipedia. 



print("\nNote: not all characters are logged. \n\n")                            # stuff
print("Enter '!tell me about morse code' for a brief lesson about morse code. \n")
print('''Otherwise, type your morse code or english and it will be
translated to the other language. ''')

while True:

    tobetranslated = input("\nTranslate\n\n> ").lower()           # get input, make all letter cases the same

    if tobetranslated == "!tell me about morse code":                          # if lesson is requested, give lesson
        print(morselesson)
        
    else:                                                               # if not special inquiry, try: except: 
        
        try:                                                                                # MORSE TO ENGLISH
            direction = True

            mte()
            
            print("\n"+finishedoutput+"\n")                       # when done with translating, display translated text
            wrongdirection = input("Press [ENTER] to translate. \n\nIf translating direction has been detected wrong, press any key and press [ENTER].\n\n")

                    

        except:                                                                             # ENGLISH TO MORSE
            direction = False
            
            etm()
                    
            print("\n"+finishedoutput+"\n")                       # when done with translating, display translated text
            wrongdirection = ""                                   # morse to english is not possible, so it MUST be english to morse, therefore no need to check
    
    if wrongdirection == "":
            pass
    else:

       # morse to english is incorrect, percieved morse is english

        mte()
        print("\n"+finishedoutput+"\n")                 # when done with translating, display translated text
```

The first runs perfectly. The second, however, prints the beginning things, asks me for text to translate, and when I type anything in, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adfadfadsfasdfads.py", line 68, in <module>
    mte()
  File "adfadfadsfasdfadf.py", line 16, in mte
    tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace(" ", "π")                                   # change spaces between letters into split markers (untypeable character)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tobetranslated' referenced before assignment

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adsfadfadfafa.py", line 78, in <module>
    etm()
  File "adsfadsfadsfadsf.py", line 32, in etm
    tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace("π", " ")                                   # undoing what "try" did
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tobetranslated' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

I don't know what is wrong, I have tried isolating just the functions and necessary variables and stuff, and it still gives the error. Is it how I am using the functions or what is in the functions that is causing the issue, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It is easier to process the translation if you would store it in a dictionary, rather than two lists.

Comment: Try passing `tobetranslated` as an argument to `etm` and returning `finishedoutput` from etm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that are wrong

1. The variable `tobetranslated` that you are using inside the functions `mte`, and `etm` is not known. You need to pass that while defining and calling the function.
2. The variable `finishedoutput` that you are using outside the function is not defined. You need to define it and assign it the value returned by your function after calculating.

Below are the changes required in your code:

While defining function:

```
def mte(tobetranslated):
  ...
  return finishedoutput

def etm(tobetranslated):
  ...
  return finishedoutput
```

While calling function:

```
finishedoutput = mte(tobetranslated)
finishedoutput = etm(tobetranslated)
```

Please find below the code:

```
english = [ "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p",            # list all translateable english characters
            "q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6",
            "7","8","9","0",".",",",";",":","!","?","(",")","-","_","&","=",
            "+","$","/","'"," ", "", "",'"']

morse = [ ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",           # list all translateable morse code characters, in same order
          ".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",
          ".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....",
          "-....","--...","---..","----.","-----",".-.-.-","--..--","-.-.-.",
          "---...","-.-.--","..--..","-.--.","-.--.-","-....-","..--.-",
          ".-...","-...-",".-.-.","...-..-","-..-.",".----.","/", " ", "", ".-..-."]

def mte(tobetranslated):
  tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace(" ", "π")                                   # change spaces between letters into split markers (untypeable character)
  tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace(" / ", "π/π")                                # change morse spaces into english spaces and an untypeable character
  splitupinput = list(tobetranslated.split("π"))                                      # split along the untypeable characters, leaving spaces, and splits  
  finishedoutput = ""                                                                 # create variable for the end output, to be modified   
  for i in splitupinput:                      # "for every character in this string:"
    if i in splitupinput:                                                        # IF inputted character is valid:
      morselocation = morse.index(i.strip())                                          # find location of input morse coded text in the morse code list
      finishedoutput = finishedoutput + english[morselocation]                    # add segment of translated text to text, separation is already there
  return finishedoutput

def etm(tobetranslated):
  tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace("π", " ")                                   # undoing what "try" did
  tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace("π/π", " / ")
  splitupinput = list(tobetranslated)                                                 # divide input into individual characters to be translated
  finishedoutput = ""                                                                 # create variable for the end output, to be modified
  for i in splitupinput:                                                  # "for every character in this string:"
    if i in english:                                                        # IF inputted character is valid:          
      englishlocation = english.index(i)                                      # Find location of input character in English character list
      finishedoutput = finishedoutput + morse[englishlocation] + " "          # Add segment of translated text to output, and add separation
  return finishedoutput

morselesson = '''Morse code is a telecommunications language made of dots,      
dashes, spaces, and slashes. The letters are comprised of
dots and dashes. Spaces are represented with slashes, and
gaps between letters marked with spaces. '''                                    # Quick morse lesson from Wikipedia. 

print("\nNote: not all characters are logged. \n\n")                            # stuff
print("Enter '!tell me about morse code' for a brief lesson about morse code. \n")
print('''Otherwise, type your morse code or english and it will be
translated to the other language. ''')

while True:
  tobetranslated = input("\nTranslate\n\n> ").lower()           # get input, make all letter cases the same

  if tobetranslated == "!tell me about morse code":             # if lesson is requested, give lesson
    print(morselesson)   
  else:                                                         # if not special inquiry, try: except:  
    try:                                                        # MORSE TO ENGLISH
      direction = True
      finishedoutput = mte(tobetranslated)    
      print("\n"+finishedoutput+"\n")                       # when done with translating, display translated text
      wrongdirection = input("Press [ENTER] to translate. \n\nIf translating direction has been detected wrong, press any key and press [ENTER].\n\n")
    except:                                                                             # ENGLISH TO MORSE
      direction = False
      finishedoutput = etm(tobetranslated)          
      print("\n"+finishedoutput+"\n")                       # when done with translating, display translated text
      wrongdirection = ""                                   # morse to english is not possible, so it MUST be english to morse, therefore no need to check
    
  if wrongdirection == "":
    pass
  else:                                             # morse to english is incorrect, percieved morse is english
    finishedoutput = mte(tobetranslated)
    print("\n"+finishedoutput+"\n")                 # when done with translating, display translated text
```

Answer (score -1):

In python you can't modify variables in functions without passing them as in input first (unless it is global, or some other specific cases). In your case, to fix your error, you need to pass `tobetranslated` to both of your functions (it is best practice to use a different name inside your function than the outer name). You will run into a similar error at the end of your file with `finishedoutput` because you do not return that value from your functions. For example:

```py
def mte(text):
    text = text.replace(" ", "π")
    ...
    return morse

def etm(morse):
    morse = morse.replace("π", " ")
    ...
    return text


tobetranslated = input("\nTranslate\n\n> ").lower()
...
finishedoutput = mte(tobetranslated)
...
finishedoutput = etm(tobetranslated)
```

Answer (score -1):

Isolating is not just about code blocks. It's also about the control flow and data flow. Although you group up some of your codes into multiple functions, the data flow is not isolated in your second version. Specifically, they all rely on global variable `tobetranslated` and `finishedoutput`.

Using global variables is a bad practice most of the times, especially when you also need to modify them.

In your case, you should pass the data to be processed as function arguments, and get return values through function's return value.

```py
def etm(tobetranslated):
  finishedoutput = ""
  # Your processing logics
  return finishedoutput
```

Moreover, there are also some other common practices you could get from google, I'll say about naming convention. `finishedoutput => finished_output` will make it better. but it's off topic ;p